# Do I have problem if my travel date is just 9 days after my visa appointment?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, itineraries

I have already submitted my UK visa application.

I have an appointment at the visa application center on the 24th August 2018.

Unfortunately, in my application details, I mentioned that the intended date to travel to the UK, if I get the visa, is on the 2nd of September 2018.

Will that be an issue, as I am not able to change my application details.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the visa you can travel any date within the validity period.